# Delphi запрос к серверу

Tags: delphi

Как реализовать подклчение к серверу (ип:порт) и вывести ответы от сервера после подключения...

Например подключение к Battle.NET, я просматривал php коды подключения(там фигня правда), и логично додуматься что если я начну подключаться к батле, то получу ответы от сервера об ник и пароль и т.п.

Comment: Какие ответы? Куда подключаться? Ответы на что? Ничего не понятно.

Comment: Ну так и в чём проблема? Берёте компонент сокет и через него подключаетесь..

Comment: а как зафиксировать ответы от сервера?

Comment: По какому протоколу хотя бы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например на WinSock:

1. Откройте сокет. `WSAStartup(...), inet_addr(...), socket(...)`
2. Подключитесь к серверу. `connect(...)`
3. Отправьте запрос. `send(...)`
4. Прочитайте ответ. `recv(...)`
5. Закройте сокет. `WSACleanup(...)`